# Nutch crawl no error , but result is nothing

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I try to crawl some urls with nutch 2.1 as follows.

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

There is no error , but undermentioned　folders don't be made.

```
crawl/crawldb
crawl/linkdb
crawl/segments
```

Can anyone help me? 
I have not resolved this trouble for two days.
Thanks a lot!

output is as follows.

```
FetcherJob: threads: 10
FetcherJob: parsing: false
FetcherJob: resuming: false
FetcherJob : timelimit set for : -1
Using queue mode : byHost
Fetcher: threads: 10
QueueFeeder finished: total 0 records. Hit by time limit :0
-finishing thread FetcherThread1, activeThreads=0
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
Fetcher: throughput threshold sequence: 5
-finishing thread FetcherThread2, activeThreads=7
-finishing thread FetcherThread3, activeThreads=6
-finishing thread FetcherThread4, activeThreads=5
-finishing thread FetcherThread5, activeThreads=4
-finishing thread FetcherThread6, activeThreads=3
-finishing thread FetcherThread7, activeThreads=2
-finishing thread FetcherThread0, activeThreads=1
-finishing thread FetcherThread8, activeThreads=0
-finishing thread FetcherThread9, activeThreads=0
0/0 spinwaiting/active, 0 pages, 0 errors, 0.0 0.0 pages/s, 0 0 kb/s, 0 URLs in 0 queues
-activeThreads=0
ParserJob: resuming:    false
ParserJob: forced reparse:  false
ParserJob: parsing all
FetcherJob: threads: 10
FetcherJob: parsing: false
FetcherJob: resuming: false
FetcherJob : timelimit set for : -1
Using queue mode : byHost
Fetcher: threads: 10
QueueFeeder finished: total 0 records. Hit by time limit :0
-finishing thread FetcherThread1, activeThreads=0
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
Fetcher: throughput threshold sequence: 5
-finishing thread FetcherThread2, activeThreads=7
-finishing thread FetcherThread3, activeThreads=6
-finishing thread FetcherThread4, activeThreads=5
-finishing thread FetcherThread5, activeThreads=4
-finishing thread FetcherThread6, activeThreads=3
-finishing thread FetcherThread7, activeThreads=2
-finishing thread FetcherThread0, activeThreads=1
-finishing thread FetcherThread8, activeThreads=0
-finishing thread FetcherThread9, activeThreads=0
0/0 spinwaiting/active, 0 pages, 0 errors, 0.0 0.0 pages/s, 0 0 kb/s, 0 URLs in 0 queues
-activeThreads=0
ParserJob: resuming:    false
ParserJob: forced reparse:  false
ParserJob: parsing all
FetcherJob: threads: 10
FetcherJob: parsing: false
FetcherJob: resuming: false
FetcherJob : timelimit set for : -1
Using queue mode : byHost
Fetcher: threads: 10
QueueFeeder finished: total 0 records. Hit by time limit :0
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
Fetcher: throughput threshold sequence: 5
-finishing thread FetcherThread9, activeThreads=9
-finishing thread FetcherThread0, activeThreads=8
-finishing thread FetcherThread1, activeThreads=7
-finishing thread FetcherThread2, activeThreads=6
-finishing thread FetcherThread3, activeThreads=5
-finishing thread FetcherThread4, activeThreads=4
-finishing thread FetcherThread5, activeThreads=3
-finishing thread FetcherThread6, activeThreads=2
-finishing thread FetcherThread7, activeThreads=1
-finishing thread FetcherThread8, activeThreads=0
0/0 spinwaiting/active, 0 pages, 0 errors, 0.0 0.0 pages/s, 0 0 kb/s, 0 URLs in 0 queues
-activeThreads=0
ParserJob: resuming:    false
ParserJob: forced reparse:  false
ParserJob: parsing all
```

runtime/local/conf/nutch-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->


<configuration>
<property>
 <name>http.agent.name</name>
 <value>My Nutch Spider</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>storage.data.store.class</name>
 <value>org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore</value>
 <description>Default class for storing data</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>http.robots.agents</name>
  <value>My Nutch Spider</value>
  <description>The agent strings we'll look for in robots.txt files,
  comma-separated, in decreasing order of precedence. You should
  put the value of http.agent.name as the first agent name, and keep the
  default * at the end of the list. E.g.: BlurflDev,Blurfl,*
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>http.content.limit</name>
  <value>262144</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

runtime/local/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt

```
# accept anything else
+.
```

runtime/local/urls/seed.txt

```
http://nutch.apache.org/
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are using Nutch 2.X, you need to follow the relevant [tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial). The one that you gave was for Nutch 1.x. Nutch 2.X uses external storage backends like HBase, Cassandra so the crawldb, segments etc directories wont be formed.

Also, use `bin/crawl` script instead of the `bin/nutch` command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured out!

Comment: Thanks Tejas. I have been trying to find Nutch 2.X tutorial for a long time. All I could find is http://nlp.solutions.asia/?p=180 and nothing on Nutch wiki site. Your reply does help. Also, I never realized I have to use bin/crawl instead of bin/nutch. I have been previously using Nutch 1.X and recently started on 2.X with lot of issues. One obvious mistake I just realized from your post is the bin/nutch usage. where do I find more information about using bin/crawl script?

Comment: @user1830069 its a easy script. U can go through it and understand it.

Comment: @TejasP: I dont find that script in Nutch 2.1 bin. The only script I have is bin/nutch. Please let me know where I can find it.

Comment: @user1830069 strange. It should be in the "bin" directory. Which release are u using ? I am not sure when that script got added but if u get to the latest codebase then u can get it there

Comment: @TejasP: I am using Nutch 2.1 downloaded from http://mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache/nutch/2.1/. I dont see bin/crawl script in the "bin" directory. It only has bin/nutch script. Please let me know if you have a better link with latest codebase

Comment: @user1830069 the new script was added in the newer codebase which is being cooked-up for new release. The svn repo link for that is: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/branches/2.x/

Comment: @TejasP: Thanks for the link. The link you gave me is a development release or a production one?