# Nutch 2.x No errors, No results neither

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

I've been playing with nutch 2.x for awhile, have it set up according to the Nutch 2.x tutorial as advised in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995457/nutch-crawl-no-error-but-result-is-nothing/16028007#16028007) , still I can't figure it out - any help would be greatly appreciated.

When using the INJECT command as per tutorial, it injects the 2 URLS I have in seeds.txt:

```
nutch inject ../local/urls/seed.txt
```

but when running the script it doesn't visit any of the urls:

```
bin/crawl ../local/urls/seed.txt TestCrawl *ttp://l*calhost:8983/solr 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've now started again with a complete new install of Nutch 2.2.1 - Hbase-0.94.10 and Solr 4.4.0 as advised vy someone on the mailinglist, due to that the versions mentioned in the tutorial are years old, and now the error I'm getting is:

[root@localhost local]# bin/nutch inject /urls/seed.txt
InjectorJob: starting at 2013-08-11 17:59:32
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: /urls/seed.txt
InjectorJob: org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: �2249@localhost.localdomainlocalhost,45431,1376235201648

Comment: I think the problem is that you must use HBase-0.90.4 (maybe would work with 0.90.6) until Gora-0.4 is released.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a long time question, but I have a suggestion here。
Because nutch is apache project, so it will obey robots.txt, perhaps because of that,you got any thing。you can gedit  src/java/org/apache/nutch/fetcher/FetcherReducer.java to Uncomment

```
/*if (!rules.isAllowed(fit.u.toString())) {
          // unblock
          fetchQueues.finishFetchItem(fit, true);
          if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Denied by robots.txt: " + fit.url);
          }
          output(fit, null, ProtocolStatusUtils.STATUS_ROBOTS_DENIED,
              CrawlStatus.STATUS_GONE);
          continue;
        }
    */
```